# arraylist adding results getting doubled

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have an app which gets data from user and then displays result from the database. From that database, I push the data to ArrayList. For example, the user inputs a sentence (e.g. "Hello world"), the app will then loop over the records from the database and when it finds something, it will then display to the user that it finds a word. Like this:

**Ambiguous word: world
Meaning: meaning of the world.**

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
Cursor cursor;

    ArrayList<String> colWords = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> colMeanings = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] words;
String[] meanings;

    ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //checkAmbiguousWord();
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

            try {

                    dbHelper.createDataBase();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

            }

            try {

                    dbHelper.openDataBase();

            } catch (SQLException sqle) {

                    throw sqle;

            }

            cursor = dbHelper.getAllWords();

            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                colWords.add(cursor.getString(1));
                colMeanings.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }

            checkAmbiguousWord();
        }   
    });
}

private void checkAmbiguousWord(){
    final String textToCheck = text.getText().toString();
    List<Integer> ambiguousIndexes = findAmbiguousWordIndexes(textToCheck);
    view.setText(!ambiguousIndexes.isEmpty() ? 
            ambigousIndexesToMessage(ambiguousIndexes) : "No ambiguous word/s found.");
}

/**
 * @param text checked for ambiguous words
 * @return the list of indexes of the ambiguous words in the {@code words} array          
 */
private List<Integer> findAmbiguousWordIndexes(String text) {
    final String lowerCasedText = text.toLowerCase();
    final List<Integer> ambiguousWordIndexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    words = (String[]) colWords.toArray(new String[colWords.size()]);
    meanings = (String[]) colMeanings.toArray(new String[colMeanings.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (lowerCasedText.contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
            ambiguousWordIndexList.add(i);
        }
    }
    return ambiguousWordIndexList;
} 

public String ambigousIndexesToMessage(List<Integer> ambiguousIndexes) {
    // create the text using the indexes
    // this is an example implementation
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer index : ambiguousIndexes) {
        sb.append("Ambiguous words: ");
        sb.append(words[index] + "\nMeaning: " + meanings[index] + "\n");
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString(); 
}
```

But my problem is, every time I input the same Hello World, the result gets added.

Ambiguous word: world
Meaning: meaning of the world
Ambiguous word: world
Meaning: meaning of the world

What is it in my code that's wrong? I'm new to Java so I need your help in finding that line of code that is wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you dropping tables before another run?

Comment: no, I'm not dropping any tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each call (with a click on your button "ok"), you do not clear the ArrayList for colWords and colMeanings :

```
cursor = dbHelper.getAllWords();

colWords.clear();///added code
colMeanings.clear();///added code
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
 colWords.add(cursor.getString(1));
 colMeanings.add(cursor.getString(2));
}

checkAmbiguousWord();
```

Comment: You can do that by calling the clear() method of ArrayList class; see my edited answer and the documentation here for this class [ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Did you check the syntax of this first record ? I do not see any problems in the different loops (cursor loop and "contains" loop)

Comment: Yes I checked, but still not displaying the first record?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                colWords.add(cursor.getString(1));
                colMeanings.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }
```

You add the string to your ArrayList every time onClick is executed. Clear them before the for loop. `.clear()` method for each array.